# Powershell script to remove files older the X days, keep getting prompted to confirm for child files

Tags: powershell, script

The script below I found and tried to use this to automatically monitor a folder en delete files older then 2 days. The problem I experience is that I'm prompted with "The item at G:\test\XXX has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified".

I tried to figure out where I should put this parameter, but without success. Anyone who can help me with this?

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

# Function to remove all empty directories under the given path.
# If -DeletePathIfEmpty is provided the given Path directory will also be deleted if it is empty.
# If -OnlyDeleteDirectoriesCreatedBeforeDate is provided, empty folders will only be deleted if they were created before the given date.
# If -OnlyDeleteDirectoriesNotModifiedAfterDate is provided, empty folders will only be deleted if they have not been written to after the given date.
function Remove-EmptyDirectories([parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})][string] $Path, [switch] $DeletePathIfEmpty, [DateTime] $OnlyDeleteDirectoriesCreatedBeforeDate = [DateTime]::MaxValue, [DateTime] $OnlyDeleteDirectoriesNotModifiedAfterDate = [DateTime]::MaxValue, [switch] $OutputDeletedPaths, [switch] $WhatIf)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force -Directory | Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -File) -eq $null } | 
        Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $OnlyDeleteDirectoriesCreatedBeforeDate -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $OnlyDeleteDirectoriesNotModifiedAfterDate } | 
        ForEach-Object { if ($OutputDeletedPaths) { Write-Output $_.FullName } Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force -WhatIf:$WhatIf }

    # If we should delete the given path when it is empty, and it is a directory, and it is empty, and it meets the date requirements, then delete it.
    if ($DeletePathIfEmpty -and (Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Container) -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Force) -eq $null -and
        ((Get-Item $Path).CreationTime -lt $OnlyDeleteDirectoriesCreatedBeforeDate) -and ((Get-Item $Path).LastWriteTime -lt $OnlyDeleteDirectoriesNotModifiedAfterDate))
    { if ($OutputDeletedPaths) { Write-Output $Path } Remove-Item -Path $Path -Force -WhatIf:$WhatIf }
}

# Function to remove all files in the given Path that were created before the given date, as well as any empty directories that may be left behind.
function Remove-FilesCreatedBeforeDate([parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})][string] $Path, [parameter(Mandatory)][DateTime] $DateTime, [switch] $DeletePathIfEmpty, [switch] $OutputDeletedPaths, [switch] $WhatIf)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $DateTime } | 
        ForEach-Object { if ($OutputDeletedPaths) { Write-Output $_.FullName } Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force -WhatIf:$WhatIf }
    Remove-EmptyDirectories -Path $Path -DeletePathIfEmpty:$DeletePathIfEmpty -OnlyDeleteDirectoriesCreatedBeforeDate $DateTime -OutputDeletedPaths:$OutputDeletedPaths -WhatIf:$WhatIf
}

# Delete all files created more than 2 days ago.
Remove-FilesCreatedBeforeDate -Path "G:\test" -DateTime ((Get-Date).AddDays(-2)) -DeletePathIfEmpty

# Delete all empty directories in the Transport Fotografie folder.
Remove-EmptyDirectories -Path "G:\test"
```

Comment: have you tested each function with that dir? that would let you know where the error is coming from ...

Comment: This is very simple, you can use Notepad++, find every line that contains `Remove-Item`, there are three lines, add `-Recurse` parameter after `-Force` in those lines.

Comment: Furthermore use `Remove-Item -LiteralPath` to handle deleting files with special characters in the file names.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is too complex, the script is, objectively speaking, not very well written. There are far better methods to achieve what you intended, and they can be much simpler.

Basically, what you are trying to do can be achieved by this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "path\to\folder" -Force -Recurse -Directory | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $((Get-Date).AddDays(-2))} | %{Remove-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Force -Recurse}
Get-ChildItem -Path "path\to\folder" -Force -Recurse -File | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $((Get-Date).AddDays(-2))} | %{Remove-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Force}
```

This should delete all files and folders older than 2 days. I want to know if you find this answer helpful or not.

Comment: Tried this after some minor changes (for deleting file i used CreationTime and Lastwrite was not recognized and changed this to LastWriteTime). It returned an error: "Cannot find path 'G:\test\test 123.pdf' because it does not exist." It managed to find the file, it just failed to delete it.

Comment: Don't forget `Remove-Item -LiteralPath` rather than `Remove-Item -Path` for removing files with special file name characters in case that is the issue @user3032387.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto to what SEL3NA said...

> ***Your script is too complex***

As for this...

---

> 'automatically monitor a folder en delete files older then 2 days.'

---

Just use a scheduled task, that checks every hour (or whatever) which runs a simple command/script (as per SEL3NA example) date check which removes the matched files, or like the one I provide below.

***Point of note:***

Not all of the below is not required. It is just a sample to show an end to end approach for your use case as you state it. Only this block is needed for your ultimate goal...

```
Remove-Item -Path $(Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)).FullName
```

...the rest is logic *(which you can do whatever you choose instead)* to check yourself before you execute destructive code (add/modify/update, delete/remove/move) and validate before and after results. Never ever run destructive code without validation first. If you do not, you'll find yourself in a very bad state, especially if you have no backup(s).

You can just take the above command and manually create a scheduled task, to run it whenever you choose. Thus no need for a separate script.

```
<#
.Synopsis
   Delete legacy files
.DESCRIPTION
   Remove all files in the target folder and sub-folders that are older than 2 days.
.EXAMPLE
   ---
.NOTE
    This will check for a scheduled task for a scheduled removal.
    Creates the task if it does not exist 
    Execute the remove, reporting on begin and end state results
    Removes the task
#>

[cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$RootFolder
)

Try 
{
    If (-Not (Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'RemoveDatedFiles' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
    {
        $ExecutableAction = $(New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument "-NoProfile -command & { Remove-Item -Path $(Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
        Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)).FullName}")
        $Trigger          = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $("{0:hhtt}" -f (get-date).AddHours(1))
        Register-ScheduledTask -Action $ExecutableAction -Trigger $Trigger -TaskName 'RemoveDatedFiles' -Description 'Remove the target executable.'
    }

    Write-Host "Current file count [before] cleanup is: $((Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder).Count)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
Catch
{
    Write-Warning -Message 'Some other error occurred.'
    $PSItem.Exception.Message
}
Finally
{
    Write-Verbose "Current file count [after] cleanup is: $((Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder).Count)" -Verbose
    # Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'RemoveDatedFiles' -Confirm:$false
}
```

Running as a standalone script for testing.

```
.\Remove-DatedFiles.ps1 -RootFolder 'C:\Temp' -WhatIf
# Results via WhatIf validation
<#
Current file count [before] cleanup is: 243
...
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Temp\(MSINFO32) command-line tool switches.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Temp\23694d1213305764-revision-number-in-excel-book1.xls".
...
VERBOSE: Current file count [after] cleanup is: 243
#>

.\Remove-DatedFiles.ps1 -RootFolder 'C:\Temp'
# Results without WhatIf validation
<#
Current file count [before] cleanup is: 243
VERBOSE: Current file count [after] cleanup is: 26
#>
```

Comment: I believe LastWriteTime to be modified date. The folder I want to monitor is a folder where people can put files to share. They can put files there that haven't been modified for days, weeks or even years. Placing an old file in this folder doesn't change the modified date of that file unfortunatly. This is why I would like to use creationdate instead, but I don't want it to remove folders with creationdate older then 2 days, as someone could just have put a file in it.

Comment: What I gave is just a sample, and you choose whatever properties you need. You could add a filesystem watcher on the folder to know when files are added, removed, etc. Keep that in a log and take action on them as needed. Only you know what you need for your use case.